# Correlation Function and quadrivectors, how to simplify a triple integral?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, greens-functions, correlation-functions, propagator

> Next consider the case where $x-y$ is purely spatial: $x^0-y^0=0, \mathbf{x-y}=\mathbf{r}$. The amplitude is then $$\begin{align}
> D(x-y)&=\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{2E_\mathbf{p}}e^{i\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{r}}\\&=\frac{2\pi}{(2\pi)^3}\int_0^{\infty}dp\frac{p^2}{2E_\mathbf{p}}\frac{e^{ipr}-e^{-ipr}}{ipr}\\&=\frac{-i}{2(2\pi)^2r}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dp\frac{pe^{ipr}}{\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}
> \end{align}$$

Can someone explain to me how he simplified that triple integral into a simple one? It's from the Peskin book An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory.

Comment: Please do not post images of mathematics. On this site you are expected to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for all math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He used spherical polar coordinates in momentum space, and performed the angular integrations. In other words,

$$d^3p=p^2\sin\theta\,dp\,d\theta\,d\phi.$$

To do the angular integrations, take the polar axis along $\mathbf r$ so that the angle between $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf r$ is $\theta$.

It is important to realize that you have the freedom to introduce any coordinates that will make the computation of an integral involving vectors easy.

Comment: Shouldn't the integral over the angular coordinates give me 4pi?

Comment: No, because the dot product involves a cosine of the angle between the two vectors. If you take the polar axis along $\mathbf r$, then this angle is $\theta$. So $\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{r}=p\,r\cos\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing an integral of $d^3p$ over all of $\Bbb R^3$ you can switch to spherical polar coordinates and integrate the sphere over all of $r$ (which in this case they've just called $p$ again). Note that the first integral is over $(-\infty,+\infty)$ and the second is over $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Shoudn't the integral over the angular coordinates give me 4pi?